# Conversion to dalvik format failed with error 1 with adt r17

Tags: android, sdk, format, adt

Today i updated my ADT and SDK to the newest revision r17. Now i can't export my apps anymore
each time i try to export a singed app i get the Conversion to Dalivk format failed with error 1.

It makes no difference if i try it with or without proguard activated via the project.properties.

I hope someone can help me.

I can't post any logs or so because it doesn't give me any output ;(

Error Message:

```
Conversion to dalvik format failed with error 1
```

Cheers,
Mike

**Edit:**

The folder structure:

```
/ProjectName/src
/ProjectName/gen
/ProjectName/assets
/ProjectName/bin
/ProjectName/proguard
/ProjectName/res
/ProjectName/AndroidManifest.xml
/ProjectName/lint.xml
/ProjectName/proguard.cfg
/ProjectName/project.properties
```

There are also Android dependencies:

```
/Users/##/ViewPagerIndicator/library/bin/viewpagerlistviewlibrary.jar
/Users/##/NineOldAndroids/library/bin/nineolddroidslibrary.jar
/Users/##/ActionBarSherlock/ActionBarSherlock v3.0/library/bin/actionbarsherlock.jar
/Users/##/GreenDroid/bin/greendroid.jar
/Developer/##/annotations.jar
/Users/##/ViewPagerIndicator/library/libs/android-support-v4.jar
```

And referenced librarys:

```
/Users/##/Project Librarys/AdMob Ads v4.3.1/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.3.1.jar
/Users/##Project Librarys/SwarmLib/Swarm.jar
/Users/##/Project Librarys/heyzap-sdk-2.0.7/android-sdk/heyzap-sdk-2.0.7.jar
/Users/##/Project Librarys/google-gson-2.1/gson-2.1.jar
/Users/##/Project Librarys/Acra v4.2.3/build/acra-4.2.3.jar
```

**EDIT**

Tried to remove all libs and add them again. Tried to put external libs into the libs folder and not adding them via the properties. No difference ^^

Comment: please confirm that your android project contains proguard.cfg file.

Comment: Yeah it contains that file, but i deleted the line in the project.properties that it is used.

Comment: had to revert back for now. ;( It is not possible to get this running^^

Comment: I have exactly the same error on one of my project. Other my projects forcecloses with "Class not found" error" on device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to ADT r20 solved everything

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this: http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17

It solved both "conversion to dalvik" and "class not found" for me. I just needed to restart Eclipse after the changes the link suggested.

Answer (score 0):

In ADT 17, they changed both how ADT handles dependencies as well as upgraded proguard (to version 4.7) and created and separated `proguard.cfg` into a "global" `proguard-android.txt` and `proguard-project.txt`.

I followed the link posted by @leocadiotine (http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17), which basically says to remove all jars from your build path (and don't re-add them...ADT includes them automatically now).

I also updated my proguard to use the Android global defaults and then added my project specific proguard needs to a new `proguard-android.txt` (replacing `proguard.cfg`). Then just added

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

to my `project.properties`. (See http://tools.android.com/recent/proguardimprovements for more info).

That did it for me. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah i followed the instructions in the other thread too, but without any luck. I also deleted the proguard.cfg and removed the reference from the project.properties. Still no change. Can you go more into detail what you did with your proguard.cfg files?

Comment: Do you still get the dalvik error even when you have no `proguard.config=` line in your `project.properties`? If so then I don't think the issue is with proguard, since proguard shouldn't even run in that case.

Comment: yeah i get still the same error. commented the proguard stuff with #

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact same issue at work, several member of my team updated to version ADT v17.

ADT v17 now uses every jar file located in the libs directory including files not specified in under project's java build path. 
We relied on the fact that not all jars were loaded because my team was leaving old unused legacy jar files in the libs directory (as we developed a new version of a jar we left the old one in the libs directory). Of course now multiple versions of the same jar are being used, so this is what causes the error *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added*.

Simply clearing all the specified jars from the project's build path was not a solution; it would ruin the other devs not using ADT v17. The best solution was for to move all the legacy jars out of the libs directory (which is something we should have done in the first place :P).